# htaccess - combine rewrites into single

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a couple of RewriteRules that I'd like to combine into one. I'm not sure how to do it, though. I think look arounds would need to be used? The difference between the two is the first would match something like:

`search/foo` or `search/foo/`

and the second would match

`search/foo/10` or `search/foo/10/`

Rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?page=search&query=$1&pn=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=search&query=$1&pn=$2 [L]
```

Without using look arounds, my attempt would be

`^search/([a-zA-Z]+)/?([0-9]+)?/?$`

But i think that would match something undesirable like this?

`search/foo10`

edit:

I'm tryin to get the regex to match the following URIs:

1. `search/foo`
2. `search/foo/`
3. `search/foo/1`
4. `search/foo/1/`

Answer (score 0):

```
^search/([a-zA-Z]+)(/)?([0-9]+)?\/?$
```

will this work? you might have make '/' also as match pattern and ignore $2.Same can be followed for the trailing '/' and ignore $4.

Comment: Hi @Adi, thanks for your response. Please see my edit. I don't think that will match `search/foo`, without a trailing forward slash?